# way to update multiple documents with different values

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, nosql

I have the following documents:

```
[{
  "_id":1,
  "name":"john",
  "position":1
},
 {"_id":2,
  "name":"bob",
  "position":2
},
 {"_id":3,
  "name":"tom",
  "position":3
}]
```

In the UI a user can change position of items(eg moving Bob to first position, john gets position 2, tom - position 3).
Is there any way to update all positions in all documents at once?

Comment: 1). change the position of Bob. 2). In all documents where position > position of bob and < than previous position of bob add 1 to position field. Basically two queries, both pretty standard.

Comment: thanks, sashkello, good solution for changing position in one step. But I can sort documents in the UI client and after sorting all documents may change its positions.

Comment: If there are many updates, I've stored the sort order per user in a distinct document to solve this problem.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can not update two documents at once with a MongoDB query. You will always have to do that in two queries. You can of course *set* a value of a field to the same value, or increment with the same number, but you can not do two distinct updates in MongoDB with the same query.

Comment: Maybe it will be partially supported with the [MongoDB's New Matcher](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/51574091391/mongodbs-new-matcher).

Comment: This anwser is not longer true, check docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter

Comment: @nothing-special-here It's still true. The "multi" param allows you to update multiple documents, but not to set different values to different documents in the same update action.

Comment: it seems to be an old answer, aggregetion piple does support it now, see @Shubham answer

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`db.collection.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite) to perform multiple operations in bulk. It has been available since `3.2`.

It is possible to perform operations out of order to increase performance.

Answer (score 8):

From mongodb 4.2 you can do using pipeline in update using $set operator

there are many ways possible now due to many operators in aggregation pipeline though I am providing one of them

```
    exports.updateDisplayOrder = async keyValPairArr => {
    try {
        let data = await ContestModel.collection.update(
            { _id: { $in: keyValPairArr.map(o => o.id) } },
            [{
                $set: {
                    displayOrder: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: { obj: { $arrayElemAt: [{ $filter: { input: keyValPairArr, as: "kvpa", cond: { $eq: ["$$kvpa.id", "$_id"] } } }, 0] } },
                            in:"$$obj.displayOrder"
                        
                        }
                    }
                }
            }],
            { runValidators: true, multi: true }
        )

        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
   }
```

example key val pair is: `[{"id":"5e7643d436963c21f14582ee","displayOrder":9}, {"id":"5e7643e736963c21f14582ef","displayOrder":4}]`

Comment: could you explain your answer more please specially the (vars) (obj) ($arrayElemAt) (input) and (as: "kvpa", cond: { $eq: ["$$kvpa.id", "$_id"] } } }, 0]) keywords.
Because i have an array of objects each one contains product_id and quantity and i want to query the Product Collection to update (decrement) each product stock based on the quantity the client bought !!
thnx in advance !

Comment: you actually dont need to write first two lines , its just I am matching the _id of specific document then finding the postion in array and then update the correct value

Comment: brilliant nice understanding of the aggregation process!

Answer (score 1):

Since MongoDB 4.2 `update` can accept aggregation pipeline as second argument, allowing modification of multiple documents based on their data.

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#modify-a-field-using-the-values-of-the-other-fields-in-the-document

Excerpt from documentation:

> ### Modify a Field Using the Values of the Other Fields in the Document
>
> Create a members collection with the following documents:
>
> ```js
> db.members.insertMany([
>   { "_id" : 1, "member" : "abc123", "status" : "A", "points" : 2, "misc1" : "note to self: confirm status", "misc2" : "Need to activate", "lastUpdate" : ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z") },
>   { "_id" : 2, "member" : "xyz123", "status" : "A", "points" : 60, "misc1" : "reminder: ping me at 100pts", "misc2" : "Some random comment", "lastUpdate" : ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
> ])
> ```
>
> Assume that instead of separate misc1 and misc2 fields, you want to gather these into a new comments field. The following update operation uses an aggregation pipeline to:
>
> - add the new comments field and set the lastUpdate field.
> - remove the misc1 and misc2 fields for all documents in the collection.
>
> ```js
> db.members.update(
>   { },
>   [
>      { $set: { status: "Modified", comments: [ "$misc1", "$misc2" ], lastUpdate: "$$NOW" } },
>      { $unset: [ "misc1", "misc2" ] }
>   ],
>   { multi: true }
> )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose after updating your position your array will looks like

```
const objectToUpdate = [{
    "_id":1,
    "name":"john",
    "position":2
  },
  {
    "_id":2,
    "name":"bob",
    "position":1
  },
  {
    "_id":3,
    "name":"tom",
    "position":3
  }].map( eachObj => {
    return {
        updateOne: {
            filter: { _id: eachObj._id },
            update: { name: eachObj.name, position: eachObj.position }
        }
    }
})
YourModelName.bulkWrite(objectToUpdate,
    { ordered: false }
    ).then((result) => {
         console.log(result);
    }).catch(err=>{
         console.log(err.result.result.writeErrors[0].err.op.q);
    })
```

It will update all position with different value.

> Note : I have used here ***ordered : false*** for better performance.