# Node.js + Mongodb(only): update multiple documents failed with save() function

Tags: mongodb, find, save, nodes

The edit.js file in router:

```
    router.post('/:id', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
        const id = req.params.id;

        // casting validate
        if (id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
            if (id != undefined || id != '') {
                // Submit modified album
                album.findById(id, function(err, doc) {
                    // Update related(existed) record with old album info
                    photo.find({"album.catalog": doc.catalog}, function(err, items, next) {
                        // Update each record with new album info
                        items: items.map(function(item) {
                            item.album.title = req.body.title;
                            item.album.catalog = req.body.catalog;
                        })
                        // Try to save the documents above.
                        items.save(); // The problem is here!
                    })
                ...
            }
        }
    });
```

The EDIT js file is supposed to modify the album's title and album's catalog which I've already done that. Somehow, I found if the album is changed. Some records which have the old album info should be changed at the same time. So, I find out all the matched records. And I not only find out them correctly. And I assigned them with new values successfully.

NOW! Here is the problem. The FINAL Step!
How to save them correctly!?

The function saves () doesn't work! Here is the error:

```
events.js:137
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: doc.save is not a function
```

Everything goes well until

```
items.save();
```

So what is the exactly right way to update documents like this?
I just want to know is there any to make it without using extra lib such as mongoose.

Variables List:
id: req.params.id which came from the url.
album: a model.

```
{
    catalog: 'sampleCatalog', 
    title: 'sampleTitle'
}
```

photo: a model too.

```
{
    album: {catalog: 'sampleCatalog', title: 'sampleTitle'}
}
```

doc: the matched album records.
items: all mathched photo records with old album info.
item: each record from items.

Thanks you guys very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to map through every item to update the document with the requested value. You can just use update operation here.

```
router.post('/:id', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    const id = req.params.id;

    // casting validate
    if (id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
        if (id != undefined || id != '') {
            // Submit modified album
            album.findById(id, function(err, doc) {
                // Update related(existed) record with old album info
                photo.update(
                     {"album.catalog": doc.catalog}, // filter
                     { $set: { 
                         "album.title" : req.body.title,
                         "album.catalog" : req.body.catalog
                       }
                     }, // update values
                     { multi: true}, // options
                     function(err, result) {
                        console.log(result);

                     }
                )
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

For more reference for mongoose update, you can refer here.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html

If you want to update multiple documents with different data, i think you need to update each data separately as per this link.
[way to update multiple documents with different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207183/way-to-update-multiple-documents-with-different-values)

Or

If you want to save like you are doing, then you need to save the doc inside map.

```
photo.find({"album.catalog": doc.catalog}, function(err, items, next) 
{
    // Update each record with new album info
    items: items.map(function(item) {
        item.album.title = req.body.title;
        item.album.catalog = req.body.catalog;
        item.save(function(err, res) { console.log(res) })
     })
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This problem is perfectly solved!