# How to update multiple mongodb elements with different values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a simplified order model that looks likes:

```
order = {
  _id: 1,
  productGroups:[
    { productId: 1, qty: 3 },
    { productId: 2, qty: 5 }
  ],
  cancels:[]
}
```

Now I have an api that cancels part of the order.
The request could be something like cancel `{productId:1, qty:2}, {productId:2, qty:2}` from order where `orderId:1`. The result should be

```
order = {
  _id: 1,
  productGroups:[
    { productId: 1, qty: 2 },
    { productId: 2, qty: 2 }
  ],
  cancels:[
    {
      productGroups:[
        { productId: 1, qty: 1 },
        { productId: 2, qty: 3 }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
let order = await Order.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id: id
  },
  {
    $inc: {
      'productGroups.$.qty': cancelQty //this is the part that needs fixing. how do I get different cancelQty according to productId
    },
    $push: {
      cancels: {
        products: cancelProductGropus
      }
    }
  },
  { new: true }
);
```

Now I know I can just `findOne`, update the model with javascript, and then `.save()` the model. But if possible I would like to do this update in one go. Or if it is not possible, can I fix the schema so that I can do such update in a single request?

Comment: As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207183/way-to-update-multiple-documents-with-different-values) it is not possible to update multiple documents with different values.

Comment: With MongoDB version 4.2 you can use an aggregation to update the array elements, as in your case. The `updateOne` method uses aggregation instead of the _update_ operation.

Comment: @prasad_ looks like a potential solution! Thanks for letting me know