# UpdateMany documents with different values

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection called **options** with this schema

```
value: string;
isCorrect: boolean;
justification: string;
```

I want to update many documents (by id) where each option has a different value in one query.

Is it possible ?

Comment: you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207183/way-to-update-multiple-documents-with-different-values)

Comment: Try using **bulk operations**. This allows sending all the updates to the database server as a single call, and is efficient (than individual calls for each update). Also, the option for unordered operation can get better performance. See [Bulk](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/).